# vmware changes usb data structure

Tags: usb, virtual-machine, vmware

I have vmware on my Windows 7 and I connected my usb device to my virtual machine (win 7) but some functions of my usb device don't work correctly on vm so I analyzed my usb output data using Putty software and I saw some thing is wrong in vm.

When I connect usb device to vm some structures of output data(bits) change, I also checked it on my virtual xp and even several computers, and the result was the same.

What is wrong with it and what is the solution?

Comment: The solution to (supposed) defects in VMware products is to contact VMware support.